# C# / AutoCAD .NET API: Read Excel Spread Sheet & Draw Objects based on Data

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, autocad-plugin

I am working on a project where I have integrated C# with AutoCAD. What I am going to do is make an AutoCAD command that uses C# (in Visual Studio) to read an Excel Spreadsheet (which is Electrical Engineering data) and then based on the data in the spreadsheet, it will then draw the appropriate graphical object in AutoCAD.

The Spreadsheet: [(picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmpxn.png). The "Service" Column describes the type of equipment we will show on a schematic diagram (drawn in AutoCAD). For example, if the equipment is a compressor, then the program should draw our predefined compressor schematic in AutoCAD, or if the equipment is a VFD pump motor, then the program should draw our predefined VFD schematic in AutoCAD.

In AutoCAD: The schematic diagram is pre-drawn, and the coordinates are easy to work with in the C# code. The difficult part is that I want to read the spreadsheet "section" column and then use this column to instruct the coordinates for placing the graphical schematic objects. For example, if the Section value of the column is 1A, I am trying to place this object at (x= 7.25, y=12, z=0). Then if the section value is 3A, then place the schematic object at its designated x,y,z value. Doing this all while selecting the correct schematic object based on the other "Service" column is a little over my head. I came up with a possible method, but I am gonna have to write a ton of duplicate code and that's why I came here to ask for help.

**Problem/My Question:** I am not sure about the best way to approach how to use C# to select the correct schematic object from the "Service" column of the spreadsheet, then place the graphical object where is belongs based on its "Section" value of the same spreadsheet. ***How would I efficiently approach this with writing C#?***

So far, I have been able to read the spreadsheet into memory and draw everything in the schematic diagram ("OneLineBackground" in code below) except the equipment objects that need placement on x,y,z grid by section.

I have two C# files: One is "Commands" where I am building basic AutoCAD 
commands. The other is "Logic" where I am calling the methods from the "Commands" class.

Here is Logic file:

```
    class Logic
{
    #region draw one-line diagram CURRENT DWG
    [CommandMethod("ElecOneLine1")]
    static public void ElecOneLine1()
    {
        string Path = Commands.SelectSpreadsheet();
        System.Data.DataTable table = Commands.ReadExcelToTable(Path);
        Commands.InsertBlocksCurrentDwg();
        Commands.DrawOneLineBackgroundCurrentDwg("OneLineBackground", 35.5478, 23.3750, 0, table.Rows[0]);



    }
    #endregion
```

Here is the "Commands" class:

```
    public class Commands
{

    #region Open File Dialog to load spreadsheet
    [CommandMethod("LoadSpreadsheet")]
    static public string SelectSpreadsheet()
    {
        Document doc =
          Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;
        OpenFileDialog ofd =
          new OpenFileDialog(
            "Select Excel spreadsheet to link",
            null,
            "xls; xlsx; xlsm",
            "ExcelFileToLink",
            OpenFileDialog.OpenFileDialogFlags.DoNotTransferRemoteFiles
          );
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr =
          ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (dr != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            return null;
        ed.WriteMessage(
          "\nFile selected was \"{0}\".",
          ofd.Filename
        );
        return ofd.Filename;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Read Excel Spreadsheet to Table
    public static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelToTable(string path)
    {
        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
        System.Data.DataSet set = new DataSet();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable sheetsName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "Table" });
            string firstSheetName = sheetsName.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheetName);
            OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connstring);
            ada.Fill(set);
            conn.Close();
        }
        return set.Tables[0];
    }
    #endregion


    #region Insert AutoCAD Block Definitions into current dwg from template (.dwt)

    [CommandMethod("InsertBlocksCurrentDwg")]
    static public void InsertBlocksCurrentDwg()
    {
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        using (Database OpenDb = new Database(false, true))
        {
            OpenDb.ReadDwgFile("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CADautomation\\ElecOneLines.dwg",
                System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, true, "");

            ObjectIdCollection ids = new ObjectIdCollection();
            using (Transaction tr =
                    OpenDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                //For example, Get the block by name
                BlockTable bt;
                bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(OpenDb.BlockTableId
                                               , OpenMode.ForRead);


                if (bt.Has("OneLineBackground"))
                {
                    ids.Add(bt["OneLineBackground"]);
                }
                if (bt.Has("vfdPumpMotor"))
                {
                    ids.Add(bt["vfdPumpMotor"]);
                }
                if (bt.Has("compressor"))
                {
                    ids.Add(bt["compressor"]);
                }

                tr.Commit();
            }

            //if found, add the block
            if (ids.Count != 0)
            {
                //get the current drawing database
                Database destdb = doc.Database;

                IdMapping iMap = new IdMapping();
                destdb.WblockCloneObjects(ids, destdb.BlockTableId, iMap, DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore, false);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Draw Block in correct coordinates current dwg
    [CommandMethod("DrawOneLineBackgroundCurrentDwg")]
    static public void DrawOneLineBackgroundCurrentDwg(string name, double x, double y, double z, System.Data.DataRow dr )
    {
        Database db = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction myT = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            //Get the block definition
            string blockName = name;
            BlockTable bt =
                db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord blockDef =
              bt[blockName].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            //Also open paper space - we'll be adding our BlockReference to it
            BlockTableRecord ps =
              bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)
                                                      as BlockTableRecord;
            //Create new BlockReference, and link it to our block definition
            Point3d point = new Point3d(x, y, z);
            using (BlockReference blockRef =
                   new BlockReference(point, blockDef.ObjectId))
            {
                //Add the block reference to  paper space
                ps.AppendEntity(blockRef);
                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blockRef, true);
                //Iterate block definition to find all non-constant
                // AttributeDefinitions  

                foreach (ObjectId id in blockDef)
                {
                    DBObject obj = id.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    AttributeDefinition attDef = obj as AttributeDefinition;
                    if ((attDef != null) && (!attDef.Constant))
                    {

                        using (AttributeReference attRef = new AttributeReference())
                        {
                            attRef.SetAttributeFromBlock(attDef, blockRef.BlockTransform);


                            if (attRef.Tag == "ATTTEST1")
                            {
                                attRef.TextString = dr.Table.Rows[6][0].ToString();
                            }

                            //Add the AttributeReference to the BlockReference
                            blockRef.AttributeCollection.AppendAttribute(attRef);
                            myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(attRef, true);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            //complete db transaction
            myT.Commit();
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

Comment: I'm confused at what you're trying to do: Ben why not just just read the coordinate values from the section column of the excel table? I've managed to solve this problem, but i read it from a database. It's very doable. basically all the information I wanted was in the database row: coordinates, and blockname. And i simply created a method called draw_block(Point3d, blockname) which subsequently drew the block. of course i had to iterate through all the rows in the table. it's not pure OOP but it does the job.

Comment: I think I may have to look into that option. I did get this project to work. The program will read a spreadsheet and draw the oneline diagram with a for loop.